# Hover color inside select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

By using Jquery, I am trying to change the hover color inside a `select` box from the default blue to red. I know that hover color of the `select` input is operating system dependent not browser dependent, but I am getting close to the desired effect.

My code below works only if I define a size for `select`. Does nothing for a simple `select`. And I just can't get it why...

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7bP2W/1/

**Code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(event) {
    $('select').on('mouseenter','option',function(e) {
      $(this).css({ "background-color": "red", "color": "white"});
    });

    $('select').on('mouseout','option',function(e) {
      $(this).css({ "background-color": "white", "color": "black"});
    });

});
```

Tested in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Opera. Does not work in IE11.

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed correctly that `select`s are (annoyingly) operating system dependent, for understandable (yet still annoying) reasons. The above solution requires that you still define a `size`, however.

There is no reason to alter a simple `select` without some tricks. If you really want to make sure your `select`s are styled in another matter, it may be worthwhile looking into [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), a jQuery plugin for select boxes.

What they do is change the `select`s into `div`s and `span`s that are styled to look like a `select`. For example:

```
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-single" style="width: 350px;" title="">
    <a class="chosen-single chosen-default" tabindex="-1">
        <span>Choose a Country...</span>
        <div>
            <b></b>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="chosen-drop">
        <div class="chosen-search">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2">
        </div>
        <ul class="chosen-results"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The plugin is then used to add functionality and style it to look better.

Regardless, what you have now is probably the most you'll be able to accomplish without a plugin like Chosen (unless you choose to build it yourself).

Comment: check fiddel link again

Comment: Thank you! Will look into that, but was hoping this could be achieved without external plugins...

Comment: @user3002057 As mentioned above, you could endeavor to write it yourself, but I wouldn't recommend such. The CSS file is 11KB and the JS file 27KB. Probably won't hurt your project that much, in terms of bandwidth.

Comment: @Luxelin - Unfortunately, Chosen apparently does not have support for <datalist>. I need that, seems I'm stuck...

Comment: @user3002057 Here's [a list](http://www.sitepoint.com/16-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/) of some other jQuery drop down plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot change the styles for these elements! `<select>`or `<option>`. They are HTML tags and are rendering itself the time of webpage load.